# Evaluate $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f(x)^3$where $f$ is a differentiable function from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus

Evaluate $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f(x)^3$ where $f$ is a differentiable function from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Can you help me?

Comment: Use the chain rule.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Product rule is also an option since $f(x)^3 = f(x)f(x)f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us take the situation $y=f(x)^n$ where $n$ is any rational number.
Then use the chain rule as follows;
Put $u=f(x).$ Then we have $y=u^n$
$$dy/dx=(dy/du).(du/dx)=nu^{n-1}. df/dx=n(f(x)^{n-1}(df/dx).$$

For example, if $y=\sin ^3 x$ then $dy/dx=3\sin^2 x \cos x.$

Answer (score 0):

With the chain rule:

$$ (f(x))^3)'=3f(x)^2 f'(x).$$